# Computing Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to show that

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{e^x-1} dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}
\end{equation}

Please note that this is the Lebesgue integral.

My current strategy is to note that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \frac{x}{e^x} \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}
\end{equation}
 And to write the RHS as a geometric series, which I've written as: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}xe^{-x(n+1)}$.

So my integral is thus:
\begin{equation}\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}xe^{-x(n+1)}
\end{equation}

I know that I can flip the integral and the summation (by monotone convergence theorem), i.e.: Work with $\sum \int$, but is this worth doing?

Also, I'm fairly certain I will take the limit of the improper integral, am I right in thinking that the upper variable of integration will be $n$so I will be taking the limit as $n$ approaches infinity of the integral from $0$ to $n$ of the geometric series from infinity to $n$?

Any input on this problem will be much appreciated!

Comment: "upper variable of integration"? The procedure is going in a good direction. Your questions I don't understand. Just continue the computation.

Comment: There's no such thing as an improper Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @Chappers, thanks for the clarification, I don't know why I was thinking this! @ Alamos: Sorry for the confusion, I think the "confusing" question stemmed from my thought that I could evaluate as an improper integral

Comment: Note http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, after using the MCT, you have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} x e^{-nx} \, dx, $$
and the integral evaluates to
$$ \int_0^{\infty} x e^{-nx} \, dx = \frac{1}{n^2} \int_0^{\infty} ye^{-y} \, dy = \frac{1}{n^2}, $$
by integrating by parts or using the definition of the Gamma-function.

Comment: Should the summation be indexed from 0 or 1? Does this matter?

Comment: Our sums are equivalent: $n+1$ starting from $0$ is the same as $n$ starting from $1$; I just wrote it this way to look neater.

Comment: This is what I figured--just wanted to be sure. Thanks for the advice. EDIT: On looking at your solution above, I noticed that the part I was not seeing was the use of integration by parts (or gamma). This is so obvious, thanks again for the help